# multiuser communication and SNR

Tags: digital-communications

The signal received from an uplink communication is given by: $r(t)=\sum_{i=1}^{K}s_i(t) \ast h_i(t,\tau)+n(t)$ where $K$ is the number of users, $s_i(t)$ is the signal for the user $i$, $h_i(t,\tau)$ is the impulse response of the channel and $n(t)$ is the gaussian noise whose SNR for the simulation is: $SNR=20$ dB.

The question is to determine the SNR of the system in dB. To find it I do: $SNR_{syst}=10log_{10}(\frac{E(|\sum_{i=1}^{K}s_i(t) \ast h_i(t,\tau)|^2)}{E(|n(t)|^2)})=10log_{10}(\frac{|\sum_{i=1}^{K}s_i(t) \ast h_i(t,\tau)|^2}{10^{-SNR/10}})=10log_{10}(|\sum_{i=1}^{K}s_i(t) \ast h_i(t,\tau)|^2)+SNR$

Are you agree with me?

Comment: What is the "SNR of the system"? Is this supposed to be the total received signal power divided by the noise power?

Comment: And what is "SNR for the simulation" and how is it different from "SNR of the system". I think a clear definition of SNR for both is needed.

Comment: A correction is needed. $r(t)$ must be replaced with $r(t,\tau)$